# Large AWS S3 Prefix Deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 prefix with deprecated data that requires deletion. It contains hundreds of millions (~450m) .bins, so deleting via AWS CLI recursively seemed to be off the table. It would appear that Lifecycle Management is the "idiomatic" way to approach this in AWS. I set the following rule:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "prefix1",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "/prefix/path"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 1
            },
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 1
            }, 
            "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
                "DaysAfterInitiation": 1
            }
        }, 
        {
            "ID": "prefix2", 
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "/prefix/path2"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 1
            },
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 1
            }, 
            "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
                "DaysAfterInitiation": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This was submitted approximately 52 hours ago. I am still seeing *all* of the objects in the AWS UI. Does anyone know the timing of such a process and when I might expect to see the deletions reflected in the UI?

Comment: Do your paths actually start with a leading / ?

Comment: Yes, as I am targeting a subfolder. It didn't return any sort of error. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is almost certainly the error.  It's technically possible to start S3 objects with a `/`, but it's rare.  Do you actually need to use `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname//prefix/path2/object` to list one of these objects.

Comment: To clarify: Try it without the leading `/` and wait up to 48 hours.